# Result of expressions in Haskell with monads

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm currently preparing for my final exam regarding Haskell, and I am going over the Monads and we were giving an example such as:

Given the following definition for the List Monad:

```
instance Monad [] where
  m >>= f = concatMap f m
  return x = [x]
```

where the types of `(>>=)` and `concatMap` are

```
 (>>=) :: [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b]
 concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
```

What is the result of the expression?

```
> [1,2,3] >>= \x -> [x..3] >>= \y -> return x
  [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3] //Answer
```

Here the answer is different from what I thought it to be, now we briefly went over Monads, but from what I understand `(>>=)` is called bind and could be read in the expression above as "applyMaybe". In this case for the first part of bind we get `[1,2,3,2,3,3]` and we continue to the second part of the bind, but `return x` is defined to return the list of x. Which should have been `[1,2,3,2,3,3]`. However, I might have misunderstood the expression. Can anyone explain the wrong doing of my approach and how should I have tackled this. Thanks.

Comment: You should start by expanding `>>=` and `return`, replacing them by their definition.

Comment: "from what I understand (>>=) is called bind and could be read in the expression above as applyMaybe" -- The name "applyMaybe" would only make sense in the `Maybe` monad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this case for the first part of bind we get [1,2,3,2,3,3]

Correct.

> and we continue to the second part of the bind, but "return x" is defined to return the list of x. Which should have been [1,2,3,2,3,3].

Note that, in...

```
[1,2,3] >>= \x -> [x..3] >>= \y -> return x
```

... `x` is bound by (the lambda of) the first `(>>=)`, and not by the second one. Some extra parentheses might make that clearer:

```
[1,2,3] >>= (\x -> [x..3] >>= (\y -> return x))
```

In `\y -> return x`, the values bound to `y` (that is, the elements of `[1,2,3,2,3,3]`) are ignored, and replaced by the corresponding values bound to `x` (that is, the elements of the original list from which each `y` was generated). Schematically, we have:

```
[1,     2,   3] -- [1,2,3]
[1,2,3, 2,3, 3] -- [1,2,3] >>= \x -> [x..3]
[1,1,1, 2,2, 3] -- [1,2,3] >>= \x -> [x..3] >>= \y -> return x
```

Comment: That's a great diagram at the end

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, helped me understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's be clear how this expression is parsed: lambdas are *syntactic heralds*, i.e. they grab as much as they can to their right, using it as the function result. So what you have there is parsed as

```
[1,2,3] >>= (\x -> ([x..3] >>= \y -> return x))
```

The inner expression is actually written more complicated than it should be. `y` isn't used at all, and `a >>= \_ -> p` can just be written as `a >> p`. There's an even better replacement though: generally, the monadic bind `a >>= \q -> return (f q)` is equivalent to `fmap f a`, so your expression should really be written

```
[1,2,3] >>= (\x -> (fmap (const x) [x..3]))
```

or

```
[1,2,3] >>= \x -> map (const x) [x..3]
```

or

```
[1,2,3] >>= \x -> replicate (3-x+1) x
```

At this point it should be pretty clear what the result will be, since `>>=` in the list monad simply maps over each element and concatenates the results.

Comment: I see what you meant, but my Prof. originally intended it to be like that. But yeah probably would have helped if she had it just like you illustrated. Thanks.